# App is not found in play store after creating a production release

Tags: google-play-console

The app was build and it was on internal test mode for about 1 month after it was reviewed. I created a production release skipping the alpha and beta test because it was ready to be launch.

After the production release was created, I saw a message saying that the app is being reviewed on the dashboard on Google Play Console. After it was reviewed, it was published but it was label as Internal Beta and I can't find it on the Play Store while searching or it. The version of the app is the old one on the Internal Test. There is no information about what is the problem and how to get the app to publish.

Answer (score 1):

Try to access directly - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=YOURPACKAGENAME

1. If you are able to access the right version - Great. It's not appearing in search, my be you need to work on marketing.
2. If you are able to access old version - wait for some time, it's being updated. Sometimes it may take upto 7 days.
3. If you are unable to access, your app is removed. You should appeal to Google.